# Troubleshooting TemplateDoesNotExist Error in Django Despite Correct Configuration

Tags: html, django

I'm relatively new to Django and encountering an issue with template loading in my project. Despite following tutorials and setting up my project structure correctly, I'm facing a TemplateDoesNotExist error.

Here's my project structure:

```
storefront\__pycache__
storefront\storefront\__init__.py
storefront\storefront\asgi.py
storefront\storefront\settings.py
storefront\storefront\urls.py
storefront\storefront\wsgi.py

playground
playground\__pycache__
playground\migrations
playground\templates
playground\__init__.py
playground\admin.py
playground\apps.py
playground\models.py
playground\tests.py
playground\urls.py
playground\views.py
db.sqlite3
manage.py
```

In my settings.py, the template configuration is as follows:

python

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

However, when trying to render a template using the render function in my view:

```
#python

from django.shortcuts import render

def say_hello(request):
    return render(request, 'playground/hello.html')
```

I'm encountering the TemplateDoesNotExist error for playground/hello.html. I've verified my project structure, and it appears to be correct.

Could someone provide guidance on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it? Any beginner-friendly explanations or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So what is in `templates`? You did not specify this in the file tree?

Comment: pardon me  for my clumsiness, sir it is listed just like you mention in your answer,
"playground/templates/playground/hello.html"
I forgot to mention it, and I appreciate that you have given me your time.

Answer (score 1):

The template should be placed in:

```
playground/templates/playground/hello.html
```

or in any other template directory but thus with a subdirectory named `playground` under that `templates/` directory.

The name of the app is thus *repeated*. This allows to *override* templates from different apps. For example in case you want to override the `admin` templates, you could put a template in `playground` named `playground/templates/admin/some_template.html` to override *`some_template.html`* from the `admin` app.